# How I can push file onto Android Device (NexusS) using eclipse or adb?

Tags: android, push, device

### *Description*

I'm trying to ***Push file (.so library) onto Android Device (Samsung NexusS)*** `"system\lib"` folder using Eclipse. But when I press "***Push a file onto the device***" an error appears:

> [2011-06-24 15:41:21] Failed to push
>   selection: Read-only file system

### *Researches*

To solve this problem I search through internet and find some articles and documentations, but nothing helps me, here are some articles and documentations which I have tried.

- [***Read-Only File System" when trying to ADB Push an App***](http://androidforums.com/droid-all-things-root/91799-read-only-file-system-when-trying-adb-push-app.html)

  Here users suggest to write `adb shell sysrw`, but when I an permission denied error appeared:

  > sysrw: permission denied

---

- [***Copying Files to or from an Emulator/Device Instance***](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#copyfiles)

  Here on Android Developers Forum I found "***You can use the adb commands pull and push to copy files to and from an emulator/device instance's data file. Unlike the install command, which only copies an .apk file to a specific location, the pull and push commands let you copy arbitrary directories and files to any location in an emulator/device instance.***"

---

I also try to run `adb remount` command, but same permission error appeared:

> remount: permission denied

### *Question*

***How I can push file onto Android Device (NexusS) using eclipse or adb ?***

Comment: Did you try to push the files other than system directory ? like sdacrd ? Typically without having a root access one cannot push to system directory.

Comment: I try and it pushed to sdcard. But I need to push it to "system" folder

Comment: As I edited my comment previously , I guess you will have to root your phone to push to system directory.

Comment: And how I can do that ? How I can have a root access ?

Comment: :) search for rooting Samsung Nexus S in google and there are side effects of rooting your phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have done rooting of my device and push files into it.

To root your Android Nexus S device check [***How to get root and recovery for Nexus S on Windoes 7***](http://vitobrothersoft.com/2011/07/06/how-to-get-root-and-recovery-for-nexus-s-on-windoes-7/).
After do this:

```
$adb shell
#mount -o remount, rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
#cat (file which you want) > (destination path)
```

Thats All !

Answer (score 3):

Typically access to system folder requires root permission, so unless you have rooted your phone i.e. you have superuser permission its not possible to access system folder or change its permission.

Check this:
[***Rooting samsung Nexus S***](http://www.samsunguniverse.com/forum/how-root-your-samsung-nexus-i9020-t796.html),

Comment: I cant use `fastboot devices` command because "The program can't start because AdbWinApi.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix problem." what does this mean ?

Comment: I have Rooted my Android and now how I can push file into it ?

Comment: change permission of system folder, from readonly to read write.