# Unable to write to sdcard in Android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, sd-card

I'm using the File Explorer in Eclipse and clicking on the "Push a file on device" option on the sdcard folder.  I get a "Failed to push the item" message.  Most likely this has to do with the fact that the file has the "d - r - x" permissions and not the "w".  Any idea in how I could change that folder permission (within File Explorer or otherwise) level so that I can push a file to it?  Thanks!

Comment: Try to run eclipse in admin mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to Android virtual Device manager-->Edit-->Hardware-->new-->sdcard support

or check these similar questions for some good info

[how to change permission of DDMS / File Explorer / sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633697/how-to-change-permission-of-ddms-file-explorer-sdcard)

[How I can push file onto Android Device (NexusS) using eclipse or adb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466916/how-i-can-push-file-onto-android-device-nexuss-using-eclipse-or-adb)

[How can I change the Read/Write Permissions of /mnt/SDcard folder on Kindle Fire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451319/how-can-i-change-the-read-write-permissions-of-mnt-sdcard-folder-on-kindle-fire)

Comment: I don't see a "Hardware" option.  When I open AVD, I get a list of my AVDs.  I select one of them and click on "Edit".  However, I don't see a hardware selection.  I do see sd card and I have it set to 512MB.

Comment: I agree with TheDude. I also cannot see the hardware selection feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
go to  c:/document setting/android

(1 in android folder right click on that and uncheck  read-only
```